# Design of Inductor DCR Current Sensing Scheme

Tags: power, voltage-regulator, inductor

How do we start the design of a DCR current sensing circuit? Do we start with the capacitor value or the resistor value? How do we choose the magnitude of the values of the RC filter components? I understand that there is the classic expression for the matching condition but what about the values per se?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Do we start with the capacitor value or the resistor value?*

A simple run in a simulator will help you find values that make sense but, there is one thing that overrides anything else; you want the resistor in series with the capacitor to be as high as possible so that the RC limb largely does not affect the inductor performance. Here's a scenario of a 10% duty square wave voltage applied across a 10 μH inductor that has an ESR of 10 mΩ: -

[image]

The middle graph shows current in the inductor i(R1) and, the voltage across the capacitor is pretty much in step with it thus, it can be relied upon to give a reasonable indication of inductor current but, only when there is little inductor saturation.

So, R and C are 1000 Ω and 1 μF but you can change this to 10 kΩ and 100 nF if you want: -

[image]

So, the rule is, make the resistor in series with the capacitor as big as is necessary to avoid fundamentally upsetting what the inductor is meant to do in your circuit but, keep an eye on the capacitor value getting too small like less than 100 pF.

> *How do we choose the magnitude of the values of the RC filter
> components?*

Well, I think you know that this relationship has to hold: -

$$\dfrac{L}{R_{ESR}} = C\cdot R_{SERIES}$$

> *I understand that there is the classic expression for the matching
> condition but what about the values per se?*

Pick the resistor value in series with the capacitor to be as high as possible is my first step. Then use a simulator is my 2nd step.